# Set Multiple Workbook, when opening more than one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a samll issue, I would like to be able to set workbooks as variables like so `Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkBook`, which is easy and great, however I now have to be able to open multiple unique workbook ranging from 2 to 50 or so depending on what I'm using  the code for.

Ideally I would like to havethe first file selected as `1Book` then the second file selected as `2Book` etc. So they can be easily reference later on in the code

Using this idea I would need to use a for loop, something like

```
For i = 1 To NUMBEROFOPENEDWORKBOOKS

    WorkBookName = i & "Book"


    Set WorkBookName = ActiveWorkbook

Next i
```

Where, `NUMBERIFOPENEDWORKBOOKS` is sudo code for a variable that defines how many workbooks i've selected, and then placed witin the `For Each` section of the code below.

I open the workbooks using the code below.

```
Set FileChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ' Opens a File Exploer dialog box '

With FileChoice ' This is used to set what is being displayed '

    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True  ' Enables the abilty to select more than 1 file
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails ' Sets the start location '
    .Show ' Allows it to be seen '

    For Each oFD In .SelectedItems ' This is used to create a file path used to open the file

        FilePath = oFD
        Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

    Next oFD

End With
```

I tried to add a for loop within the code using `.selectedItems` but that only confirmed that it would fail

I hope all of this made sense.
Thank you for any help you can give.

**EDIT 1**
I have taken the advide form the comment and trie to use an Arraty function to solve this, however when I run the code below, I get a `Object Required` error.

Have I made a totaly clearing error that I can't see?

```
Public WorkBookArray() As Excel.Workbook
Sub Channel_1()

Set FileChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ' Opens a File Exploer dialog box '

    With FileChoice ' This is used to set what is being displayed '

        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True  ' Disables the abilty to select more than 1 file
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails ' Sets the start location '
        .Show ' Allows it to be seen '

        ReDim WorkBookArray(.SelectedItems.Count, 1)

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems ' This is used to create a file path used to open the file

            FilePath = oFD
            counter = counter + 1
            Set WorkBookArray(counter,1) = Workbook.Open(FilePath)

        Next oFD

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at arrays, an array of workbooks `dim array() as excel.workbook`.  Redim the array to `.selecteditems.count` and then use a counter in your existing loop, to say `set array(counter)=workbooks.open(filepath)`

Comment: Ahh thats a very clever way. I shall have a fidle with that and see what I can come up with. Thank you

Comment: or a [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/collection-object)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have had a play with your idea, and cant seem to get it working, I've added an edit to the end of  the question with my new code . Can you see my mistake?

Comment: `set` should be there I believe.  Or even the native `workbooks()` collection may suffice?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the 1, see below using an array to simulate the filedialog results.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the filedialog, but a similar approach, this is how I would tackle your issue

```
Public arrWorkbooks() As Excel.Workbook

Sub open_workbooks()

Dim strWorkbookPaths(2) As String
Dim intCounter As Integer

strWorkbookPaths(0) = "C:\Workspace\Dummy Data\test1.xlsx"
strWorkbookPaths(1) = "C:\Workspace\Dummy Data\test2.xlsx"
strWorkbookPaths(2) = "C:\Workspace\Dummy Data\test3.xlsx"

ReDim arrWorkbooks(UBound(strWorkbookPaths))

For intCounter = 0 To UBound(strWorkbookPaths)

    Set arrWorkbooks(intCounter) = Workbooks.Open(strWorkbookPaths(intCounter))

Next intCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a

```
Workbook
```

that must be:

```
Workbooks
```

And you don’t need a 2D array

So your code can be as follows:

```
Public WorkBookArray() As Excel.Workbook
Sub Channel_1()
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ' Opens a File Exploer dialog box '
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True  ' Disables the abilty to select more than 1 file
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails ' Sets the start location '
        .Show ' Allows it to be seen '

        ReDim WorkBookArray(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems ' This is used to create a file path used to open the file
            counter = counter + 1
            Set WorkBookArray(counter,1) = Workbooks.Open(oFD)
        Next 
     End With
End Sub
```

Of course, as soon as any of those workbook gets clised, the corresponding item in WorkBookArray() becomes a null reference